# Blender Geometry nodes animation like UE GDC opening

Tags: geometry-nodes, unreal-engine

I was trying to make this scene from UE gdc opening https://youtu.be/gcElD8KvDLs?list=PLZlv_N0_O1gYUMkyGerbUGedE7y-XQSJR Followed few tuts here and there to get this far but no idea how to make these pointy at the this side like the video If you know can you please help me out on how to make that possible

This right side won't be pointy.
[image]

The Node tree.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You might be able to use something from [this](https://youtu.be/uRAfhJQFjRo) Twisting Crystals tutorial that Polyfjord did several years ago. However it was done in Blender 2.8 and doesn't use Geometry nodes so may not be suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make your curves pointy on one side you can try this.
[image]

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
My previous answer was not 100% right, so I tried to make what you need in a different way. Hope it helps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is true for just one of 'em but it requires much more than that to pull it off for many of 'em

Comment: Just tested them with a bunch of curves, works fine. What is exactly the issue?
https://gyazo.com/2a1dd775fae5fe96eede02f539ce316e

Comment: I fixed my solution, please take a look

Comment: Thank you, Buddy